# Java - Parameters are not being passed into function when expected to be

Tags: java, function, parameters, rgb

I am attempting to run a method rgbScore() which passes in parameters from previous methods to calculate the difference between two pixels of a image. I would expect the result to be the difference between the two pixels but all I get is (0,0,0) ...

```
public void TypeButtonPressed()
{

    filteredImage(GetType());
            int type = GetType();

            filteredrgbValue();
            originalrgbValue();
            rgbScore(originalred, filteredred,  originalgreen, filteredgreen, originalblue, filteredblue); //THIS METHOD

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Original RGB Value:" + oRGBValue + "\nFiltered RGB Value:" + fRGBValue + "\nScore:" + rgbDiff, Options[type], JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);


}
```

...

```
public String rgbScore(int originalred, int filteredred, int originalgreen, int filteredgreen, int originalblue, int filteredblue){

        int redDiff = originalred - filteredred;
        int greenDiff = originalgreen - filteredgreen;
        int blueDiff = originalblue - filteredblue;

        return rgbDiff = "(" + redDiff + "," + greenDiff + "," + blueDiff + ")";


     }
```

I have declared the variables at the top of the class as follows:

```
public int filteredred; public int filteredgreen; public int filteredblue;
public int originalred; public int originalgreen; public int originalblue;
```

< Additional Information >

filteredrgbValue();

```
public String filteredrgbValue(){ 
        BufferedImage filtered = filteredImage;

        Color filteredRGBValue = new Color(filtered.getRGB(125, 125));

        int filteredred = filteredRGBValue.getRed();
        int filteredgreen = filteredRGBValue.getGreen();
        int filteredblue = filteredRGBValue.getBlue();

        return fRGBValue = "(" + filteredred + "," + filteredgreen + "," + filteredblue + ")";        

    }
```

originalrgbValue();

```
public String originalrgbValue(){
        BufferedImage original = unfilteredImage;

        Color originalRGBValue = new Color(original.getRGB(125, 125));

        int originalred = originalRGBValue.getRed();
        int originalgreen = originalRGBValue.getGreen();
        int originalblue = originalRGBValue.getBlue();

        return oRGBValue = "(" + originalred + "," + originalgreen + "," + originalblue + ")";     

    }
```

Comment: Are you assigning a value to your `int` declarations? Consider writing an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. Remember that [by default, uninitialized `int` have a value of zero](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Comment: I have not assigned a value to my variables as I want them to use the values generated in the functions? How would I get over this obstacle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating new variables in your methods which are hiding your member variables.  Remove the type declarations, for example:

```
public String filteredrgbValue(){ 
        BufferedImage filtered = filteredImage;

        Color filteredRGBValue = new Color(filtered.getRGB(125, 125));

        // you are declaring new variables here, hiding your member variables...
        //int filteredred = filteredRGBValue.getRed();
        //int filteredgreen = filteredRGBValue.getGreen();
        //int filteredblue = filteredRGBValue.getBlue();

        filteredred = filteredRGBValue.getRed();
        filteredgreen = filteredRGBValue.getGreen();
        filteredblue = filteredRGBValue.getBlue();

        return fRGBValue = "(" + filteredred + "," + filteredgreen + "," + filteredblue + ")";        
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Fixed! :-)

Comment: @eamuldowne If you problem was solved, please consider marking an answer as the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have never initialized variables, you have just declared the vars.
defualt valu for int is 0 and until you dont initialize your vars it will have default vals.

Comment: Thank you!

Where would I need to intialize them? Would it look something like this... `filteredred = filteredred;` ... if so, where would I put it?

Comment: what are this methods ? filteredrgbValue();
            originalrgbValue();  initialization is assigning a value to those vars.. are these methods doing the intialization?

Comment: `filteredrgbValue();` gets the RGB value from the filtered image and `originalrgbValue();` gets the RGB value from the original image. They both return a RGB value. I want to subtract the R,G,B channels to get a new R,G,B value.....

Comment: Here's the two functions >> [link](https://i.gyazo.com/1f4db26bf0efde3d9a30dcca5eadabe4.png)

Comment: @eamuldowne Please edit your post with the additional code.  Don't post an image link of your code.

Comment: @whiskeyspider Updated!